# Deploy a (WAR) on Tomcat remotely with windows 2003 server

Tags: java, tomcat, curl, windows-server-2003

I want to upload a .war from my local system (windows server 2003 without cURL) on a tomcat 8 with a POST request, i've seen that there's some tips here :  [Manager App HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely)

I tried something like this :

```
wget --post-file="C:/My/war/file/on/Local/system" 
"http://<username>:<password>@<tomcatserver>:<port>/manager/text/deploy?
path=/my/path/to/save&update=true"
```

But I end up with this :

```
Connecting to <tomcatserver>:<port>... connected.
Retrying.
```

and it retrying in loop...

What's wrong with that ?

(Also I couldn't find a cURL version for windows 2003 server so I'm using wget.)